# Django Attribute Error: object has no attribute '__state' and removing __init__ from Class

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a model for a sample Django application "webshop", and I'm having trouble at understanding what my problems stem from.

The `models.py` I have is:

from django.db import models

```
class Product(models.Model):

    def __init__(self, title, quantity, description, image_url=""):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        self.quantity = quantity
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.image_url = image_url
        
    def sell(self):
        self.quantity = self.quantity - 1
```

and what I want to be able to do with it is to initialize it with something like:

`toy1 = Product(title="Bear plush", description="Fluffy bear plush toy", quantity=10)`

I can call it with

`print(toy1.quantity)`
`print(toy1.title)`
`toy1.sell()`
and so on fine, but doing `toy1.save()` returns the error

```
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute '_state'
```

Upon googling about the problem, I came across the fact that it's not advised to use **init** here, but the offered alternatives in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects
both utilize a logic where the first call of the class function is different from the initial call.

If the problem I'm facing is due to relying in `__init__`, how can I get rid of it while still being able to initialize the objects with `toy1 = Product(title="Bear plush", description="Fluffy bear plush toy", quantity=10)`
or is my problem something completely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the model you are trying to create should look like:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[URLValidator()])

    def sell(self):
        self.quantity = self.quantity - 1
        self.save()
```

Django takes care of the instantiation, so you don't need the `__init__` bit.

Comment: This is otherwise functional, but when I try to run `toy1.save()` in gui bash, I get the error 
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: table webshop_product has no column named title`

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't yet created your models in the database. Everytime you modify your models, you need to run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` then `python3 manage.py migrate` to update these changes to the database. It may be worth your while to read the [Django models reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/)

Comment: I'll do that. accepting your answer in the mean time as it sounds reasonable. Thanks for the help

Comment: This works! Thanks again for all the help, wouldn't survive in studying programming if it wasn't for stackoverflow